# I have a asp.net c# project, what is the difference between <%=myfunction(); %> & <%# myfunction() %>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected string myfunction() {
   return "abc";
}
```

In one of my pages I can show the `"abc"` in the webpage by using `<%# myfunction() %>`. But in another page it doesn't work unless I use `<%=myfunction(); %>` instead.

What is the difference and why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you show us the complete code of both pages? Esp the headers?

Comment: Jon Limjap: Esp? guess you mean asp :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<%= myfunction(); %>` would be used to output the return value of `myfunction` in a page.

`<%# myfunction(); %>` would be used to output the return value of `myfunction` in a control that is data bound (for example, inside an asp repeater control).

Take a look at [this overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860#1a) for more information on data binding.